# Upgreded android app to compile sdk 33 and target sdk 33 after upgrading not able to receive the notification on android 13 OS phones

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

```
    Map<String, String> body = Collections.emptyMap();

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        body = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + body);
        //messageBody = body.toString();
    }

    sendNotification(body);
    
}


 private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> messageBody) {
    Intent intent = null;

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        createChannel(notificationManager);
    }


    String notificationType = messageBody.get("notificationType");
    String typeOfPatient = messageBody.get("");

    if ((notificationType != null ) && (notificationType.equalsIgnoreCase("chatmessage"))){
        intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("notify", true);
    }


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0  /*Request code*/ , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    String title = "Patient Name " + messageBody.get("name");
    String message;
   


   


}
```

upgraded compile SDK and target SDK 30 to 33 after upgradation not able to receive any notification on android 13 OS phone.